# Create write once Fields in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have an SharePoint 2010 farm.

I want to create a custom `DocumentLibrary` with a `custom ContentType`. I create the `Listdefinitions` in Visual Studio.

But i want to use fields that i can fill in only after uploading or creating a new document, and after then that not editable (but read only).

The properties ShowInNewForm and ShowInEditForm are not working for this, because uploading a document will always use EditForm.

How can i arrange that?

Comment: how your way for add value to Field? Have you use Event Receiver For that?

Comment: I want to add value with the forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can register an event receiver and a custom *EditForm* form in your doclib. The [ItemUpdating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemupdating.aspx) method of the event receiver class will make sure that nobody (a tool or a page) can modify the fields by the SP object model after they the item was created:

```
public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    // Cancel the update according to the content of AfterProperties.
    properties.Cancel = true;
    properties.ErrorMessage = "...";
}
```

The custom *EditForm* form would present read-only properties in read-only HTML elements if the form is opened for other than the first time. Well, you wouldn't necessarily need to do this because any changes done in the form would be rejected by the event receiver, but the user experience would not be nicer with the form. Actually, if you don't need the safety against the SP OOM changes you can go just with the form; users won't be able to modify the fields by just the SP UI.

--- Ferda